# Why runtime error happened after right compiling for c++ class constructor

Tags: c++

When I run `./out`, it throw error notice like this:

```
[1]    66798 segmentation fault  ./a.out
```

But it can pass compiler without error:

```
clang++ -std=c++11 -g test.cpp
```

Code like this, I found it break near `hobby->push_back(hb)` by gdb.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct X {
public:
    X(const string &, const unsigned, const string &);
    X(const X &);
    X &operator=(const X &);
    ~X();
    void print();
private:
    string name;
    unsigned age;
    shared_ptr<vector<string>> hobby;
};

X::X(const string &nm, const unsigned ae, const string &hb):
    name(nm), age(ae)
{
    hobby->push_back(hb);
    cout << "X()" << endl;
}

X::X(const X &obj)
{
    cout << "X(const X &obj)" << endl;
}

X &X::operator=(const X &obj)
{
    cout << "X::operator=(const X &obj)" << endl;
    return *this;
}

X::~X()
{
    cout << "~X()" << endl;
}

void X::print()
{
    cout << "name: " << name << '\n'
        << "age: " << age << '\n';
    for (auto const &hb : *hobby) {
        cout << hb << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
    X a = ("bjcharles", 30, "swimming");
    a.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) "_But it can pass compiler without error_" If the code compiles, it does not mean, that it will run correctly. 2) `hobby->push_back(hb);` Here, you are dereferencing a shared pointer, which doesn't point anywhere (is `nullptr`). Do you really need `shared_ptr`? Or pointer in general?

Comment: This does not compile `X a = ("bjcharles", 30, "swimming");` => `X a("bjcharles", 30, "swimming");`.

Comment: @CharlesWang Or better yet, just use a `std::vector`. Why do you even need the `shared_ptr`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a shared pointer:

```
shared_ptr<vector<string>> hobby;
```

Which you dereference by doing:

```
hobby->push_back(hb);
```

This is undefined behaviour because you never assigned to the `shared_ptr` an instance of a `std::vector` and so you are likely dereferencing a `null` pointer. Undefined behaviour means anything could happen, including it working or in your case, a segmentation fault.

You need to either:

1. Create the memory, preferably in the constructor under an initialization list:

   `X::X(const X &obj) :
       hobby(std::make_shared<std::vector<...( ...`
2. Dont use a smart_ptr for this. `std::vector` is already a great RAII type. Unless you need to share this pointer (which from your class definition you dont) then just using a `std::vector` directly (without the encasing `shared_ptr`) will be fine.

---

As a final note, this should help you realize that you cannot rely on the compiler to check your code. Just because something compiles doesnt mean it will work. For example, this will compile:

```
int arr[5];
arr[6] = 5;
```

But this in no way means this is correct or safe and that it wont cause runtime errors. It only means that it compiles.